# How to get logs for print() function from iOS App on mac console?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to print service calls request body, header and response from the iOS app on mac console.

I'm getting the logs for print statement when debugging with Xcode, but how to do it without Xcode in the debug build?

Answer (score 1):

Use `os_log` instead of `print`. Now you can read the output in the Console application on the Mac.

Comment: Yes correct. Read more about os_log here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/os_log